# Masters degree in business engineering or management engineering

Tags: engineering

Is it possible to have a masters degree in business engineering or management engineering when you don't have a first degree? But i have more than 10 years professional experience

Comment: Not sure, but masters degrees are basically free money for the schools, so I'm curious about this too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no, mostly because the undergraduate degree is validation that you've covered some baseline subject matter.  Even in more vocation-based undergraduate schools you usually need to take courses (writing, math, humanities) that might not be directly related to the subject matter.

That said, there are schools that may be willing to trade a certain amount of professional experience for a certain amount of credit towards an undergraduate degree, or schools that might let you pursue both degrees at the same time.  You'll have to shop around.

Answer (score 0):

A Bachelor's degree is necessary.

Many colleges accept some credits earned through [CLEP](https://clep.collegeboard.org/).  Check the published rules first and then double-check with the college directly.